# Could not find method defaultConfig() - Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I recently (3 days ago) started learning Android Studio. I bought an Eclipse game project to play with, but I am getting errors. And when I fix that error, I get a new error.

The current one that I can't seem to fix is:

> Error:(2, 0) Could not find method defaultConfig() for arguments
>   [build_2ttwbw07u5v666j5nx2ciclk3$_run_closure1@5ac759e5] on project
>   ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project. Open
>   File

My `build.gradle` (Module: App):

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.getemplate.catadventure"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26

        sourceSets.main {
            jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
            jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
        }

        ndk {
            moduleName "player_shared"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }


android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"

    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile files('libs/dagger-1.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/support-v4-19.0.1.jar')
}
```

Anyone know why I am getting the error?

Here's a screenshot:
[image: screenshot error]

Thank you very much for your time and assistance in this matter.

Comment: I know tried and move the code bit "android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"

    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
}
 to the top, but now I get the message "Could not find method android() for arguments [build_2ttwbw07u5v666j5nx2ciclk3$_run_closure1@6f070f25] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project."

Answer (score 3):

This is because you didn't add code for android application plugin which is `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`. You also need to move the `defaultConfig` inside the android like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

  compileSdkVersion 26
  buildToolsVersion "26.0.3"

  defaultConfig {
   ...
  }

}

dependencies {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I fixed the issue by just re-creating a new project since I had a feeling my code a bit screwed from trying to fix other errors. I know how another error:
Build command failed.
Error while executing process C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\APPS\FamousDex\app\src\main\jni\Android.mk

I Googled this but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Congratulations then! ;)

Comment: The error probably because you don't have a correct NDK path

Comment: Have you try adding the ndk path to `local.properties`? something like this: `ndk.dir=/opt/android/sdk/ndk-bundle`. Please be noted that is a line for ndk in Linux, I don't know about Windows.